# Why does the word 'mexicano' not have an accent at 'e' while 'México' does?

Tags: acentuación

The word México has an accent on the 'e', but the words 'mexicano' and 'mexicana' which are derived from México do not.

I wonder why these two words do not have accents above 'e'.

Comment: Lea las reglas de acentuación. *mexicano*: palabra grave terminada en vocal, por lo tanto NO se debe tildar. Por otro lado, *México* es un nombre. Los nombres no necesariamente siguen las reglas de acentuación; no obstante la costumbre es que las sigan. Al ser esdrújula, lo más ‘razonable’ es tildarla.

Comment: Accent placement rules depend on where the stressed syllable is in the word (counting from the end). The position of the stressed syllable often changes when making derivative words, so the presence and position of accents also changes.

Comment: @tac ¿Los nombres no siguen las reglas de acentuación pero los acentuamos por costumbre? ¿Y el resto de palabras sí es totalmente obligatorio? ¿Qué autoridad refrenda esas afirmaciones?

Comment: There are really two questions here.  First where does the stress fall?  Second, why isn't there a written accent mark?  The stress in Mexicano falls on the *a*.  It's unnecessary to have a written accent to indicate where the stress falls, due to the accent placement rules.

Comment: @RubioRic Los nombres extranjeros, si no se traducen, se escriben de acuerdo a la grafía endónima. Pensá en los equipos de fútbol. Por ejemplo, se escribe Manchester United, y la pronunciación es MANchester. Los nombres de personas, ciudades, equipos, etc., en donde el idioma es el español *suelen escribirse* de acuerdo a nuestras reglas de ortografía. Pero te sorprendería si te dijera que mucha gente decide no escribir las tildes en sus nombres. Y es completamente legal.

Comment: @tac ¿Cuál es el equivalente argentino de "mezclar churras con merinas"? Las reglas de ortografía NO son leyes. Entiendo que te refieres a algunos nombres propios y no a los nombres en general, que es lo que afirmabas arriba, sin tener prácticamente nada que ver con la pregunta.

Comment: En español, una palabra derivada de otra no necesariamente debe tener la tilde en el mismo lugar. Sé que hay una clasificación (grave, aguda, esdrújula) pero no si hay alguna regla respecto a dónde debe ir la tilde. Como hablante nativo, las tildes de la mayoría de las palabras más frecuentes que uso están en mí memoria. Lo que sí te puedo sugerir es que recurras al [diccionario](https://dle.rae.es/mexicano) cuando no sepas cómo se escribe una palabra.

Comment: @RubioRic Juro que no entendí nada de lo que dijiste. Dije que los nombres **no necesariamente** siguen las reglas de acentuación. **En general**, los que refieren a cosas, lugares y personas relacionadas al idioma español sí las siguen. ¿Qué es lo que no entendés?

Comment: Terciando en la discusión sobre los acentos en los nombres, leo en el [DPD](https://www.rae.es/dpd/tilde): "_El uso de la tilde se atiene a las reglas que se detallan a continuación y que afectan a todas las palabras españolas, incluidos los nombres propios_". Sobre los extranjerismos, resumo lo que dice: los no adaptados deben ir entre comillas o en cursiva; los adaptados siguen las normas de acentuación.